# Does `perf stat` (and `time` !) show incorrect results when running `perf trace -s`?

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I am running kernel-5.0.9-200.fc29.x86_64 (and the `perf` package with the same version number).

In the command below, the reported `msec task-clock` is much greater than the total of `seconds user` and `seconds sys`.

Are these the real figures, or is it the result of a limitation or bug?

If they are all the real figures, then what does the `task-clock` mean?  It is not the CPU time (`user` + `sys`).  Also, I would wonder why the second command below takes about 10 seconds less of real time, but *50 seconds more* of CPU time :-).

EDIT: during the first few seconds, the first command shows a lot of messages in red: `LOST 5 events!`

`$ sudo time perf stat perf trace -s dnf -y --releasever=30 --installroot=$HOME/nspawn/fedora-30 --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo=fedora --enablerepo=updates install systemd passwd dnf fedora-release vim-minimal`

...

```
         91,686.29 msec task-clock                #    0.463 CPUs utilized          
           535,179      context-switches          #    0.006 M/sec                  
             5,244      cpu-migrations            #    0.057 K/sec                  
           399,484      page-faults               #    0.004 M/sec                  
   238,663,625,948      cycles                    #    2.603 GHz                    
   348,081,456,496      instructions              #    1.46  insn per cycle         
    51,406,362,901      branches                  #  560.677 M/sec                  
     1,207,307,303      branch-misses             #    2.35% of all branches        

     198.215217338 seconds time elapsed

       5.570430000 seconds user
      11.160145000 seconds sys


5.59user 11.36system 3:18.45elapsed 8%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 28212maxresident)k
2760inputs+0outputs (16major+6641minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Compare:

`$ sudo time perf stat dnf -y --releasever=30 --installroot=/home/alan-sysop/nspawn/fedora-30 --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=fedora --enablerepo=updates install systemd passwd dnf fedora-release vim-minimal`

...

```
         69,277.16 msec task-clock                #    0.371 CPUs utilized          
            22,223      context-switches          #    0.321 K/sec                  
               858      cpu-migrations            #    0.012 K/sec                  
           380,117      page-faults               #    0.005 M/sec                  
   187,946,998,307      cycles                    #    2.713 GHz                    
   312,329,248,251      instructions              #    1.66  insn per cycle         
    44,516,425,061      branches                  #  642.584 M/sec                  
     1,020,032,328      branch-misses             #    2.29% of all branches        

     186.623370416 seconds time elapsed

      62.278802000 seconds user
       6.379658000 seconds sys


62.31user 6.57system 3:06.86elapsed 36%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 423700maxresident)k
0inputs+2562096outputs (23major+379286minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no actual inconsistency.

The `seconds user` / `seconds sys` display the `rusage` statistics of the direct child only (all threads in the process) wheras the counters, by default, *inherit* down to all child and grandchild processes.

That is, the *lower* CPU times are only with respect to the `perf trace` utility wheras the *longer* times include the actual `dnf` process.

You can also confirm that by running

```
perf stat --no-inherit perf trace ...
```

You cannot include grandchildren in the resource usage summary.

P.S. You should not assume that the behavior of the resource usage summary remains the same for different `perf` versions.

Comment: +1.  Yeah, it would be cool if a future version of `perf stat` was able to avoid this sort of confusion about its output somehow.

Comment: Wait.  This is very promising, but then I am confused by `time`.  E.g. It's not a co-incidence that `time` and `perf stat` both print 62.3s user time.  `/usr/bin/time` seems to manage to include the grandchild (`dnf`) in its resource usage summary.

Comment: I believe this has to do with how the processes wait for their children. See [`getrusage()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage). I haven't managed to figure out how exactly `perf` does that.

Comment: I think `perf stat` does the same as `/usr/bin/time`.  Proof:  `sudo perf stat sh -c 'stress -t 1 -c 1; echo'` shows `0.995054000 seconds user`.

Comment: So, the answer is because `perf trace` never calls wait() for the child process :-).  It just exits its mainloop [when it receives SIGCHLD](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/tools/perf/builtin-trace.c#L1234).  I will accept this answer if it qualifies that the observed behaviour is a quirk of `perf trace` (of course other programs may have the same quirk, but it is the less common behaviour :-).